# I installed Anaconda3 on my Mac for Python. However when I try to use numpy it says ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, macos, numpy

So I installed Anaconda3 from online. When I try to use numpy in a code, it gives me an error. Is there anything else that I need to do in order to use these python packages ? 
Does this involve anything in terminal or just the python shell ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use/run Python from the Anaconda installation to get anaconda modules running. Changing path for python should fix any import errors.

Comment: How do I do that? I went on the anaconda folder in my documents and tried to open python from there, but it still gives me an error. I'm new to python and still learning, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You'll have to export anaconda path to your .bash_profile with shell or terminal. Exporting path should look something like  'PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH'. Google how to export path to bash profiles for instructions.